# angular.min.js.map not found, what is it exactly?

Tags: angularjs

When I load the page and check chrome console i find these errors:
[image]

what exactly are map files in angular?

I did reference the angular.min.js but not the angular.min.js.map.
I am using the angular 1.2 rc release by the way and I just started seeing these errors when i switched to this release.

```
ERRORS:
GET http://localhost:44786/Scripts/angular-route.min.js.map 404 (Not Found)       :44786/Scripts/angular-route.min.js.map:1
GET http://localhost:44786/Scripts/angular-animate.min.js.map 404 (Not Found) :44786/Scripts/angular-animate.min.js.map:1
GET http://localhost:44786/Scripts/angular-resource.min.js.map 404 (Not Found) :44786/Scripts/angular-resource.min.js.map:1
GET http://localhost:44786/Scripts/angular.min.js.map 404 (Not Found) :44786/Scripts/angular.min.js.map:1
```

Comment: I can't read your image, but I found this: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/

Comment: ah.. so it seems that this is not an angular exclusive event... let me read it first.. thanks very much

Comment: hey monkey, can you answer the question.. you are right..

Comment: possible duplicate of [sourceMappingURL from jquery generates 404 error in apache](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18157535/sourcemappingurl-from-jquery-generates-404-error-in-apache)

Answer (score 399, accepted):

As eaon21 and monkey said, source map files basically turn minified code into its unminified version for debugging.

You can find the .map files [here](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.12/). Just add them into the same directory as the minified js files and it'll stop complaining. The reason they get fetched is the

```
/*
//@ sourceMappingURL=angular.min.js.map
*/
```

at the end of angular.min.js. If you don't want to add the .map files you can remove those lines and it'll stop the fetch attempt, but if you plan on debugging it's always good to keep the source maps linked.

Comment: You don't need to remove the lines, as the .map files only gets fetched with Developer Console open :)

Comment: True, but the original question was specifically about errors appearing in dev tools. Also it's never a bad thing to reduce unnecessary 404s in your server logs.

Comment: According to me it's not about the server logs, but about the chrome errors he receives. I have to admit, it will generate server logs and your comment is valid ;)

Comment: If you have multiple files such as bootstrap.css, angular-messages.min.js, angular-route.min.js, etc. even those files will contain such `sourceMappingURL` at the end of each of those files. Deleting that line in each of those files will get rid of the pesky error messages in the Developer console.

Comment: In Safari browser, these JS Error casing issues: [Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (angular.min.js.map, line 0).  thanks for providing the file links.

Answer (score 108):

Monkey is right, according to the link given by monkey

> Basically it's a way to map a combined/minified file back to an unbuilt state. When you build for production, along with minifying and combining your JavaScript files, you generate a source map which holds information about your original files. When you query a certain line and column number in your generated JavaScript you can do a lookup in the source map which returns the original location.

I am not sure if it is angular's fault that no map files were generated. But you can turn off source map files by unchecking this option in chrome console setting

[image]

Comment: +1 for the chrome console setting; much better than editing the source or having to download the map files when unneeded.

Comment: +1 for this over a year later. Bravo. What a mystery that setting was !

Comment: In chrome, open settings dialog by: Press F12 to open `Developer Tools` > Click on Settings button in the upper-right corner of `Developer Tools`

Comment: Is there a similar setting for safari?

Comment: Safari is Settings > Sources > Source Maps. Uncheck to get rid of those errors