# Thinking way to debug angular

Tags: angularjs

I get the following error:

```
Error: Non-assignable model expression: undefined (directive: leaflet)
    at Error (<anonymous>)
    at h (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js:43:213)
    at Object.<anonymous> (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js:43:326)
    at Object.e.$digest (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js:87:13)
    at Object.e.$apply (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js:89:198)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js:16:239
    at Object.d [as invoke] (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js:28:96)
    at c (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js:16:160)
    at tb (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js:16:356)
    at lc (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js:16:4) angular.min.js:63
(anonymous function) angular.min.js:63
```

Apart from the fact that I'm trying to indeed debug the above error, I would like to ask what is the best way to debug the code as the above error does not display the error line on the original code but the one at the angular.min.js file?

Comment: `model` is scope object and problem is in directive leaflet....set breakpoint and walk through it in console. rethinking this--- believe there is a problem in angular markup expression

Comment: There is a concept of `map` files look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425841/angular-min-js-map-not-found-what-is-it-exactly.

Comment: Start by using the non-minified version of angular.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if i seen that error the first thing i would do is check for elements that have the leaflet directive and then inspect the expression that is inside it. like this

```
<div leaflet="whatever you have here is undefined"></div>
```

Well, that's what angular is telling me anyway.

You can also use the Batarang debugging extension for angular.js