# where to find .map files in bolt-cms

Tags: bolt-cms

In bolt-cms it gives lib.min.js.map and bolt.min.js.map files are missing in chrome console. As it says these files are not in the /app/view/js/maps folder. I got referenced from previous post

> [angular.min.js.map not found, what is it exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425841/angular-min-js-map-not-found-what-is-it-exactly)

Form where I can found those map file?

Answer (score 1):

They are not committed to git, as they are quite large and would be a big performance penalty if you're not doing debugging, and therefore you won't get them in a default zip or Composer install.

If you do need to debug any of the JavaScript in Bolt, you can generate them:

```
cd app/view/
npm install
grunt updateBolt updateLib
```

Note that the location of Gruntfile.js has changed for the upcoming 2.2 release to app/src/