# Why we use minified version of Angularjs (Reason to give preference to angular.min.js over angular.js even if we are adding angular.min.js.map)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, minify, source-maps

I added angular.min.js to my project and faced this issue.[image: Chrome Developer Console screenshot]

> http://localhost:8000/AngularProject/angular.min.js.map 404 (Not
>   Found) angular.min.js.map:1

---

Upon research, I found that adding angular.min.js.map got rid of the "404 (Not Found)" error.  I also found the reason for "angular.min.js.map": *we add it because "source map files basically turn minified code into its unminified version for debugging"*.

But, isn't the reason for using the minified file saving space and making the application faster?  Now if we use angular.min.js we have to add angular.min.js.map also.

Wouldn't it be much simpler to just add angular.js rather than adding two files(angular.min.js, angular.min.js.map).  What is the meaning of having a minified version of angular.js?

Comment: You don't *need* the sourcemap. You only need it if you want to debug the minified code. They only get loaded when your developer tools are open

Comment: @RGraham No it is not duplicate

Comment: @RGraham you should post your first comment as the answer, and add how to remove the sourcemap comment (//@blahblah.js.map) in case he just wants the error to go away

Comment: @RGraham then when it is good to use angular.js because as a developer you need to debug your application again and again.Then see the error on console or add two files is not a good thing ?

Comment: @SparshKhandelwal the map file only gets downloaded if you have developer tools open.  Normal users browsing your website won't download the map file.  It's only for the developer.  It is like the *.pdb files you use to debug binaries.

Comment: @user120242 thanks ; thats i didn't know :)

Comment: I don't know why this question was voted down, its not immediately obvious and something someone new to Angular may wish to know, may people may want to use this answer as a reference

Comment: @MaxCarroll There's nothing wrong with the question itself, but it's probably because the information is widely available through searching. Nobody here has said anything different than is discussed in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425841/angular-min-js-map-not-found-what-is-it-exactly). Questions with no *research effort* are equally as bad as a bad question.

Comment: @RGraham i copied this line from the same question 'source map files basically turn minified code into its unminified version for debugging'. But yeah might be because of my inexperience ,i didn't understand that .map file will be used by browser only when we open the debugging mode.

Comment: @RGraham but it asks the question from a different perspective and understanding (or lack thereof), which some newbie might stumble upon  using similar keywords (ie: perspective) that may not reach the other thread.  I think flagging it as duplicate is good enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are right and wrong.

This .map file is for debug only and get downloaded by your browser when you open the debug mode.

Comment: i am not wrong , but i didnt know something and believe in reasoning :). but yeah , come to know about new thing :)

Comment: @SparshKhandelwal If this answers your question, press the accept checkmark.  If you would like a more detailed explanation, post a comment, and I (or others) can give it a go and try to give you an answer that helps you understand it better.

Comment: @user120242 sorry for delay, thanks for help !!. Now everything is clear , studying angular so if any doubt comes then will ask :)

Comment: @SparshKhandelwal No worries; just trying to guide you a bit since you seem new to the site.  Glad you understand it better now :)  Sourcemaps are an indispensable tool for web developers.