# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) in Safari

Tags: ruby-on-rails, interact.js

In a Rails application I am getting the following error message in the Safari console:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

for the interact.min.js.map file. However, this only occurs in the Safari browser console. Although it is included in all logging in my local development environment for Rails.

Any ideas as to why this is being displayed. I have version 1.2.8.

Comment: Do you have the `interact.min.js.map` file on your server?

Comment: Yes, I do have it on my server. Sometimes just writing the question helps, it may be related to this line: `//# sourceMappingURL=dist/interact.min.js.map` in the file itself which is similar to the issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425841/angular-min-js-map-not-found-what-is-it-exactly.

Comment: So, the question is not why it is being requested, but why my server can't find it, right? If so, you'd need to add more information including your file structure, server configurations and related error messages from your log files.

Comment: I updated my first comment (in case you missed it), I think the answer lies there.