# JS map file reference - how it is used?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, bundling-and-minification

My project has lot of js and css files that are getting referenced in the aspx pages. When i see my project files for every js / css file there is one .map file as well.
E.g-> kendo.all.min.js and kendo.all.min.js.map
When i try to search "kendo.all.min.js.map" in Visual Studio solution it is found under kendo.all.min.js but it is commented like below :

```
//# sourceMappingURL=kendo.all.min.js.map
```

When i read over web it says these files are for minifications when used in production environment but my question is how they get refreneced in prod , the code is commented and how these files know that they need to be used in production there should be some kind of mapping. What i am missing ?

Comment: I do not think these files are meant for production.

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425841/angular-min-js-map-not-found-what-is-it-exactly/18431438#18431438

Comment: What is the recommended way should we keep these files or not, i am asking wrt performance does keeping these files have performance impact ?

Comment: This special form of the comment is to denote a source map reference that can be interpreted by for instance the developer tools in the browser. But typically map files are not for production environments but for development only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.map` files aren't generally meant for production code. Their purpose is to map between a transpiled-or-otherwise-modified version of a file (which runs in the browser) and the original source file (which might look different) for debugging purposes: You can put breakpoints and such in the code that the browser is running and then, when they're reached, the browser can show the original source file and the original code for where the breakpoint is.

For production, you usually don't A) provide access to the `.map` files, or B) provide access to the original files they reference.

Comment: What is the recommended way should we keep these files or not, i am asking wrt performance does keeping these files have performance impact ?

Comment: @user662285 - Frankly, I don't know. Normally, you have the production build set up not to generate `.map` files or the comments that refer to them. I would *expect* that a browser would ignore the comment referring to the `.map` file unless someone opened the devtools in the browser, but... Really, the answer is: Look at the config for your build too and have it not generate these for production builds.