# Sourcemap in jQuery 1.10.0 causes insecure content when loaded over HTTPS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ssl, https

i have a small problem by using HTTPS. By using SSL in my Rails-Application Chrome shows me the following error-message:

```
The page at 'https://www.thesitename.de/shop/counter/checkout/cart' was loaded over HTTPS, but displayed insecure content from 'http://www.thesitename.de/assets/jquery-1.10.0.min.map': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.
```

Does that mean that the jquery-file is not loaded via HTTPS or that some requests in the jquery-script are over HTTP? In the sourcecode of the Site i don't see any HTTP-Javascript-includes. The jquery-File is local stored.

I hope this is enough information and someone can help me.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide the script tags that are in your page, just to be sure.  Also, this answer may help you... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056497/simple-jquery-code-works-fine-until-site-is-loaded-via-https

Comment: thanks @RobBaillie for the suggestion, but i this doesn't work for me. the line, where the jquery is loaded is the following: 
`<script src="https://www.thesitename.de/assets/thesitename.js?1386074141" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: And the contents of thesitename.js?

Comment: the content is jQuery v1.10.0. That's a lot of stuff, should i post it?

Comment: No, not at all.  Why did you hide the name?  Have you changed the name of the file? IIWY I'd put the name back again, just to be sure.

Comment: Also, search your page for all and any src attributes and ensure they all either state HTTPS, or nothing.

Comment: you mean 'thesitename'? yes i changed the name because that's the name of my employer and i don't want to publish it on the board. i hope you understand that. but i only changed the name here 2-times in the code-sample here. do you have any ideas? because the file is already loaded over https

Comment: i checked the source-code for all 'http' but there is no src-attribute to find :(

Comment: You described the file as being: https://www.thesitename.de/assets/thesitename.js - it's the second thesitename I'm interested in - if this is a standard jQuery distro then it makes sense to name it as such.  When I said check for 'src', I meant in the resulting HTML, not in the source-code.

Comment: sorry, of course i meant the resulting HTML not the source-code. the name of the js-file is the same as the domain-name. yes, i know that it makes not much sense to label the file with this name, but it wasn't me ^^ do you think there could be a problem which is caused by the jquery-code? is that possible? it's really strange, because there is no 'http' in the whole resulting HTML-Code ...

Comment: in the beginning of the js-file there are following lines:

`/*! jQuery v1.10.0 | (c) 2005, 2013 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/license
 //@ sourceMappingURL=jquery-1.10.0.min.map
 */`

maybe that could cause a problem(?). But i'm not familiar with the functionality of sourcemapping ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file being requested forms the sourcemap for jQuery.  This can be used by some browsers to help with debugging.

It's referenced in the download documentation here: http://jquery.com/download/

When looking at the problem elsewhere on stackoverflow I came across this: 
[sourceMappingURL from jquery generates 404 error in apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18157535/sourcemappingurl-from-jquery-generates-404-error-in-apache)

There may be useful info in there.

My advice would be to try the following:

- Remove the line from your jQuery library (this means that you won't have access to the sourcemap when you're debugging - which may not be a problem for you)
- Use a CDN to source your jQuery libraries instead - both jQuery and Google have ones.
- Try downloading a local copy of jquery-1.10.0.min.map beside your version of the jQuery distribution.

Hopefully one of the above should resolve your issue.

Comment: THANK YOU SOOO MUCH Rob!!! removing the sourcemappingurl-line was the soultion! everything works fine! :)

Comment: Yep, removing the sourceMapURL from the min.js fixed it.